# NoReverseMatch in Django Web application

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have been having a tough time debugging my code as to what mistakes i could have made in my urls.py or views.py or templates but can't figure it out.

Error logs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\student-management-system\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\student-management-system\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\student-management-system\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\student-management-system\student_management_app\StaffViews.py", line 450, in question_add
    return redirect('staff_quiz_update', quiz.pk, question.pk)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\student-management-system\venv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 41, in redirect
    return redirect_class(resolve_url(to, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\student-management-system\venv\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 131, in resolve_url
    return reverse(to, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\student-management-system\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 87, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\django-new\student-management-system\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 677, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /staff_quiz_question_add/4/question/add/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'staff_quiz_update' with arguments '(4, 5)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['staff_quiz_update/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
```

views.py

```
def question_add(request, pk):
    # By filtering the quiz by the url keyword argument `pk` and
    # by the owner, which is the logged in user, we are protecting
    # this view at the object-level. Meaning only the owner of
    # quiz will be able to add questions to it.
    quiz = get_object_or_404(Quiz, pk=pk, owner=request.user.staffs)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            question = form.save(commit=False)
            question.quiz = quiz
            question.save()
            messages.success(request, 'You may now add answers/options to the question.')
            return redirect('staff_quiz_update', quiz.pk, question.pk)
    else:
        form = QuestionForm()

    return render(request, 'staff_template/quiz_question_add_form.html', {'quiz': quiz, 'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
    path('staff_quiz_question_add/<int:pk>/question/add/', StaffViews.question_add, name="staff_quiz_question_add"),
    path('quiz/<int:quiz_pk>/question/<int:question_pk>/', StaffViews.question_change, name='question_change'),
```

templates (quiz_question_add_form.html)

```
{% extends 'quiz_base.html' %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
  <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
      <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'staff_quiz_home' %}">My Quizzes</a></li>
      <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="{% url 'staff_quiz_update' quiz.pk %}">{{ quiz.name }}</a></li>
      <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Add a new question</li>
    </ol>
  </nav>
  <h2 class="mb-3">Add a new question</h2>
  <p class="lead">Add first the text of the question. In the next step you will be able to add the possible answers.</p>
  <form method="post" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
    <a href="{% url 'staff_quiz_home' %}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" role="button">Nevermind</a>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

If you need any more info, let me know

Comment: `{% url 'staff_quiz_update' ... %}` requires *two* parameters: `quiz_pk`, and `question_pk`.

Comment: Furthermore this name does not exists, it is `'question_change'` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i was able to fix it using your approach